Sin attachment due to thoughts only
Present Shankaracharya says that in Kaliyuga there is no sin with evil thoughts but only sin is due to evil actions. But in other Yugas thoughts also sinful.
However, smritis, puaranas, etc. clearly state that evil thoughts also sinful.
Please help with me references for exception to Kaliyuga where evil thoughts do not result in sin but good thoughts result in virtue.
Note: Shankaracharya's statement is here:
https://www.facebook.com/share/p/HXnz2Xkmdi9RXSJe/

This is stated in the Bhagavata Purana. I have read it in either Dharma Bindu or in Dharma Sindhu.

I was recruiting you to come up with an answer! You didn't disappoint Thank you. @rickross

Thanks .... @Kanthri

In Mahanirvana Tantra's Chapter 4, Lord Shiva also states that same. See the following verses:


The Kali Age is but the slave of those who are free of all crookedness
and falsehood, men of candour, devoted to the good of others, who
follow Kaulika ways (67). In spite of its many blemishes, the Kali Age
possesses one great merit, that from the mere intention of a Kaulika
of firm resolution desired result ensues (68). In the other Ages, O
Devi! effort of will produced both religious merit and demerit, but in
the Kali Age men by intention merely acquire merit only, and not
demerit (68). The slaves of the Kali Age, on the other hand, are
those who know not Kulachara, and who are ever untruthful and the
persecutors of others (70). They too are the slaves of the Kali Age
who have no faith in Kulacharas, who lust after others' wives, and
hate them who are faithful to Kaulika doctrine (71)

